# Convert a string with curly brackets to a nested list object

Tags: r, json, regex, jsonlite

We have a string with curly brackets to represent nested lists:

```
x <- "{{1,2,3,4},{1,2,3,4,{Axe,Bat,Cat,Donkey}},{1,2,3,4}}"
```

How can we convert it to a nested list **R** object?

So far I have below solution, it is not ideal. The idea is to convert it to a valid *JSON* format, then use `jsonlite::fromJSON`. I would like to skip/improve quoting step, so that numbers read are numeric. Yes, I could loop through the nested list and convert `"numbers"` to numeric, but would like to avoid.

Any other non-JSON solutions are welcome, too.

```
library(jsonlite)

# translate brackets to JSON square brackets
x <- chartr("{}", "[]", x)

# wrap in quotes
x <- gsub("(\\w+)", '"\\1"', x)

# finally read as JSON
fromJSON(x)

# [[1]]
# [1] "1" "2" "3" "4"
# 
# [[2]]
# [[2]][[1]]
# [1] "1"
# 
# [[2]][[2]]
# [1] "2"
# 
# [[2]][[3]]
# [1] "3"
# 
# [[2]][[4]]
# [1] "4"
# 
# [[2]][[5]]
# [1] "Axe" "Bat" "Cat" "Donkey"
# 
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "1" "2" "3" "4"
```

Comment: can't you do a `gsub` with `[A-Z]` instead of `w`? (I don't master regular expressions)

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent same here, not regex master, OK this was simpler than I thought, feel free to add as answer.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent oh no, sorry, the input is not single letters. It was just an example, they can be more than one letter.

Comment: I prefer to left the answer to a regex master :)

Comment: Yes but `[A-Z]+` should work for multiple letters (or something like that).

Comment: OK, thanks, I will add regex tag.

Answer (score 2):

This solution does not use any packages.  It replaces innermost lists with `c(...)` and then quotes the words that start with a letter and replaces `{` and `}` with `list(` and `)` respectively.  Then it parses and evaluates that to get the result.

```
x1 <- gsub("\\{([^{]+)\\}", "c(\\1)", x) # x is from question
x2 <- gsub("([a-zA-Z]\\w+)", "'\\1'", x1)
x3 <- gsub("\\{", "list(", x2)
x4 <- gsub("\\}", ")", x3)
result <- eval(parse(text = x4))

str(result)
```

giving:

```
List of 3
 $ : num [1:4] 1 2 3 4
 $ :List of 5
  ..$ : num 1
  ..$ : num 2
  ..$ : num 3
  ..$ : num 4
  ..$ : chr [1:4] "Axe" "Bat" "Cat" "Donkey"
 $ : num [1:4] 1 2 3 4
```

This could also be written as a pipeline using magrittr:

```
library(magrittr)

x %>%
  gsub("\\{([^{]+)\\}", "c(\\1)", .)  %>%
  gsub("([a-zA-Z]\\w+)", "'\\1'", .) %>%
  gsub("\\{", "list(", .) %>%
  gsub("\\}", ")", .) %>%
  parse(text = .) %>%
  eval
```

Comment: "does not use any packages" thank you. I was thinking of gsub+eval+parse too, but failed to apply proper regex.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
jsonlite::fromJSON(txt=gsub('([A-Za-z]+)','"\\1"',chartr('{}','[]',x)))
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4

[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]][[2]]
[1] 2

[[2]][[3]]
[1] 3

[[2]][[4]]
[1] 4

[[2]][[5]]
[1] "Axe"    "Bat"    "Cat"    "Donkey"


[[3]]
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

Or you could use `alpha` ie:

```
jsonlite::fromJSON(txt=gsub('([[:alpha:]]+)','"\\1"',chartr('{}','[]',x)))
```

The issue here is to obtain a good regex such that it does not include the numeric elements.